# Avoiding excessive control flow working with Id arrays in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Multi-select lists in MVC don't seem to bind to complex models. Instead, they return an array of selected Id numbers.

I have such a control on a page, and I'm annoyed by the amount of conditional logic I've had to deploy to get it to work. The objects in question are a Staff object who can have TeamMember membership of none or more teams.

My objects are from entity framework. I added this to the Staff object:

```
public int[] SelectedTeamMembers
{
    get; set;
}
```

I can now bind to this property in my View, and users can edit the multiselect list. On posting back the edit form, I have to do this (comments added for clarity):

```
//user.TeamMembers not bound, so get existing memberships
IEnumerable<TeamMember> existingTeamMembers = rep.TeamMembers_Get().Where(t => t.UserId == user.UserID);

//if array is empty, remove all team memberships & avoid null checks in else
if(user.SelectedTeamMembers == null)
{
    foreach(TeamMember tm in existingTeamMembers)
    {
        rep.TeamMembers_Remove(tm);
    }
}
else
{
    // if team members have been deleted, delete them
    foreach (TeamMember tm in existingTeamMembers)
    {
        if (!user.SelectedTeamMembers.Contains(tm.TeamId))
        {
            rep.TeamMembers_Remove(tm);
        }
    }

    // if there are new team memberships, add them
    foreach (int i in user.SelectedTeamMembers)
    {
        if (!existingTeamMembers.Select(t => t.TeamId).Contains(i))
        {
            TeamMember tm = new TeamMember { TeamId = i, UserId = user.UserID };
            rep.TeamMembers_Change(tm);
        }
    }
}
```

I can tidy this up a bit by farming out each bit to a function, of course, but it still feels like a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Is there a neater way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should evaluate the possibility of combining your `for` and `foreach` loops into a single loop as the first step of simplifying this code.

Also, you know how to use LINQ (as evidenced by you initial `Where()` statement) so simplify the `null` conditional action as well, using LINQ and some of its helper extensions:

```
//user.TeamMembers not bound, so get existing memberships
IEnumerable<TeamMember> existingTeamMembers = rep.TeamMembers_Get().Where(t => t.UserId == user.UserID);

//if array is empty, remove all team memberships & avoid null checks in else
if(user.SelectedTeamMembers == null)
{
    existingTeamMembers.ToList().ForEach(tm => rep.TeamMembers_Remove(tm));
}
else
{
    // if team members have been deleted, delete them
    existingTeamMembers.Where(tm => !user.SelectedTeamMembers.Contains(tm.TeamId)).ToList().ForEach(tm => rep.TeamMembers_Remove(tm));

    // if there are new team memberships, add them    
    user.SelectedTeamMembers.Except(existingTeamMembers.Select(t=> t.TeamId)).ToList().ForEach(i =>
    {
        TeamMember tm = new TeamMember { TeamId = i, UserId = user.UserID };
        rep.TeamMembers_Change(tm);
    });

}
```

While this has not decreased the conditional complexity (as in all the conditionals are still there) the syntax is a lot more readable.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks - I always forget you can foreach inside a linq statement. Going to leave it here for a while in case there's anything cleverer that can be done with the binding or the EF object.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way...It relies on using the `RemoveRange` method.

**Entity - I'm using my own for demo purposes**

```
public class User
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

}
```

**Action**

```
public ActionResult Action(Guid[] selectedTeamMembers)
{



    using (var ctx = new DatabaseContext())
    {

        //
        // Start by targeting all users!
        //
        var usersToRemove = ctx.Users.AsQueryable();

        //
        // if we have specified a selection then select the inverse.
        //
        if (selectedTeamMembers != null)
        {
            usersToRemove = usersToRemove.Where(x => !selectedTeamMembers.Contains(x.Id));
        }


        //
        // Use the Set Generic as this gives us access to the Remove Range method
        //
        ctx.Set<User>().RemoveRange(usersToRemove);


        ctx.SaveChanges();

    }



    return View();
}
```

Hope this helps.